# How to hide status bar + using white light content in another view controller(swift)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to hide status bar in a first controller, but I also want it to appear in a second controller in a lightContent.

I used:

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

for light content and

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```

to hide status bar.

My problem is that set View controller-based status bar appearance to Yes/No in .plist file will disable one or another.

Comment: Do you use a tab bar and/or navigation controller?

Comment: Navigation controller, but I solved it already by: navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = .blackTranslucent I should have use my brain in first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to hide status bar in a `ViewController` you can easily do it using this code

**In viewWillAppear**

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = true
```

**In viewWillDisappear**

```
UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
```

**In info.plist**

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key><false/>
```

**In didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Add controller-based status bar false in `info.plist`

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>
```